# Unable to successfully execute MS tutorial at: "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-office-365-data"

Tags: azure

I am working on MS tutorial at "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-office-365-data".

While executing the pipeline named "CopyPipeline" I am getting error as follows:

Operation on target CopyFromOffice365ToBlob failed: ErrorCode=UserErrorOffice365DataLoaderError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Office365 data loading failed to execute. Value should be a Guid.
Parameter name: SourceLinkedService.ServicePrincipalId,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

I am not able to resolve the issue. Any inputs on this will be helpful.

Comment: What the value of service principal ID your entering on step 6? How you are created a service principal for your pipeline?

Comment: At step 6 1) Office 365 Tenant value came automatically which is equal to tenant id of "Azure Active Directory" 2) For "Service Principle ID" & "Service Principle Key" values I created my strings like "abc" & "abckey" respectively. With these values the test connection worked well.

Comment: it is very strange that test connection worked well ... but you need a proper service principal, I think you can try to use the same as you must created for step 6 of "Configure sink" part

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I have tried it already. But didn't work for "Configure sink" part.

Comment: I want make sure, "Service Principle ID" & "Service Principle Key" it is not your strings, it is properties of Application Registration from Azure AD, in the article there is a link to instruction how to create it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#service-principal-authentication